# Can SAML response contain custom data?

Tags: single-sign-on

We have multiple websites that share the same customer base but doing different kind of business. We already have a server that acts as a **centralized identity service** - it manages **customers**, their **businesses** and customer's **roles** in the businesses.

Because of the existence of this centralized identity service, we decide to add single-sign-on to this service - i.e. to **make it act as a SSO identity provider**.

A customer may have roles in multiple businesses - he could be an **admin** in business **A** and a **technician** in business **B**. When he logs in, our centralized identity service makes him to pick a business to login.

Question: does SAML response contain fields/attributes to carry this information: "The user has logged into business **B** as a **technician**"?

Comment: Yeah, that's just standard SAML. Google for SAML Attribute Statement.

Comment: I posted a broader question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72166739/how-to-create-a-single-sign-on-identity-provider-server-in-asp-net-mvc   If you can help with that, that will be great. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, that's going to be closed for lacking focus. Basically you're asking someone to explain an entire SAML implementation to you. My advice is to start with the Wikipedia page and then read the spec. It answers all your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This document answers the question I asked:

http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/Post2.0/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0.html