# How to create a single-sign-on Identity provider server in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

I am quite new to SSO and SAML. We have an ASP.NET MVC server. We need to make it act as a SSO **identity provider**, which accepts a **SAML request** from other **service provider** websites of ours, lets users to login using email, password and 2FA, then redirect back to the service provider websites with a **SAML response/assertion**.

Two of the service provider websites are created using DNN CMS, so the way our **SSO identity provider** works must be **industry-standard**, so that DNN CMS can work with it.

Questions:

1. How to create the **SAML request** on the **service provider** side? What tool I can use to create the XML?
2. How to encrypt the **SAML request**? Symmetric or asymmetric? What encryption key to use? Shall it be signed?
3. How to send the **SAML request** to the **identity provider**? A GET or POST? As query string? What is the query string name?
4. How to decrypt the **SAML request** on the **identity provider** side? How to verify the signature it it is signed?
5. How to create the **SAML response/assertion** on the **identity provider** side?
6. How to encrypt and sign the response?
7. How to send the **SAML response** back to the **service provider**? GET or POST? As a query string? What query string name?
8. How to decrypt and verify the **SAML response** on the **service provider** side?
9. How to extract information from the **SAML response**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

This document answers all the questions I listed, and the following supplier, [www.componentspace.com](http://www.componentspace.com), is a well-known and reputed SDK that can be used to create both a IdP and SP.

Comment: this one is very expensive

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend either using a commercial product or open source library. Attempting to implement this yourself and getting the security correct is a major undertaking.

Most of your questions can be answered by looking at the SAML v2.0 specification documents. This will also give you an idea of the work involved if you did decide to attempt implementing this yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you have an open source library you can recommend?

Comment: I haven't used any but have a look on www.nuget.org.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **miniOrange NuGet package** for this purpose.

I've successfully implemented SSO + MFA into ASP.NET Applications using their solutions.

LINK: https://plugins.miniorange.com/asp.net

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: miniOrange is not free as I see